# How to assign values from an array to Text boxes in Webpage using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I have an Excel sheet with as 5 rows and 3 columns containing values.
What I need is :-
-To read the values row wise each time and input into corresponding 3 textboxes in a webpag e and click submit button
- Then  page refreshes and then fetch  the next row values in excel ,assign the values to the textfields  perform the submit action

In a nutshell, how can we assign the values row wise [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1ECr.png) from an excel sheet to multiple textboxes in a page one after the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719944/read-the-rows-in-excelsheet-and-populate-in-webpage-text-box?rq=1

Comment: What have you done and what issue are you facing? Please don't ask 'help with homework' type of questions.

Comment: I have read the values from excel sheet and stored in a string arrray.My questions is how can i read the values from the array and populate it in multiple text boxes in a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

For read excel sheet and storing it into the variables in java probably the best way is to use Apache POI library .This library lets you manipulate excel documents and more. I found some example how to use Apache POI to read data from excel. After that you can you can store the cells inside the variables and use variables to insert the data into the website. Hope this gets you on the right track.

http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-read-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi